# IPtables preventing outgoing packets

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I am trying to setup firewall rules on a RHEL webserver, so that my webserver can serve up web pages and at the same time download remote files using curl/wget. Problem I am experiencing is I can only do one or the other. I've tried tweaking my iptables settings and I isolated the problem to be with outbound packets cause if I enable all outgoing, it works just fine.

This is what I am using:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 3 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Could it be something to do with **ESTABLISHED,RELATED** in my OUTPUT rule for http/https?

Comment: Yes it could be...  Do you expect all the possible outgoing connections to somehow magically be already established?  Or do you want to initiate **NEW** outgoing connections, in addition established connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prettly clearly dropped all your output packets that don't match any of the rules:

```
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

And at the same time you didn't accept *any* packets that constitute new connections and instead all your rules operate only on established connections that can never actually be established:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT ... -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED ...
```

Please read the manual page for `iptables` and especially the part describing `-m state`. Then you won't create firewalls that explicitly block your new outgoing connections and then be surprised that your outgoing connections are being blocked.

I, personally, don't think it's a good idea to use the `DROP` policy on `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains and I don't care about its usage on the `FORWARD` chain. I always use explicit REJECT/DROP rules at the and of the chain. `REJECT` is usually better for the beginning as it doesn't introduce lags and timeouts.

The best solution for you is probably to switch the `OUTPUT` policy back to `ACCEPT` and remove the `OUTPUT` rules.

Comment: Yeah that was it. But it instead of changing the default OUTPUT to accept, I decided to explicitly allow outgoing new,established rules for http/https traffic with the following: `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @PythonNoob: That's a valid approach as well, if you want to control OUTPUT carefully, which is not so common.